# timeout in sql server and attachment of db in sql express 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005-express

**Intro.**

i have made a application in vs 2008 using c# and at back end i am using sql express 2005.

**Application background:**

just like report tool in which user select some parameters and get results in cube
after she can import that result into excel or in any formats.

**problem:**

1. user mostly processing 15 to 70 months report which takes 45 mints to 1.25 hours to 
   complete but sometime result generated for 9 months and sometime 11 months not as 
   selected months -- show alert: timeout....
2. how to attach and deattach my database file when my software is installing 
   (or after installation) as my application installer installs my apps. 
   and sql express 2005

Answer (score 0):

Use sp_attach_db to attach a database to a SQL server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179877.aspx

If you're connecting to the server using a SqlCommand object, then you can set the CommandTimeout to 0 for indefinite execution. That is not advised though!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx

Comment: i have already set CommandTimeout to 0 but no change it shows me same error. can you explain why my application not processing all the selected months and it is much slow.